# Disable auto comment notifications for copies of Google Sheet files I create from a template that I own

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a template Google Sheet file and automation that makes numerous copies of.

Right now, when someone makes a comment in any of the copies I get a notification.

How can I disable that notification -- either permanently or programatically when my automation creates the copy from the template.

** EDIT **

This question was closed saying it needs more details. I'm not sure what other details I can provide.

Somehow I am getting auto-subscribed to comment notifications for Google Spreadsheet files I own/copy/create. I am trying to figure out how to disable that programatically. I already searched Google documentation/help and the communities but can't find anything. There are help articles on how to configure notifications for Spreadsheets from Tools > Notifications but that is not the same thing I am talking about -- plus I never enabled notifications that way in the first place.

These are the steps I took/am taking:

1. I have a new Spreadsheet file I created -- the template
2. I have automation that kicks off whenever someone submits a Google Form. The automation creates a copy of the template file (from #1)

That's it. And now, for some reason, whenever someone makes an comment in any of the copies created (in step #2), I am getting the email saying there is a new comment. It is that email/notification I am trying to disable.

** EDIT 2 **

Here is the code I am using to make copies of my template:

```
var template = DriveApp.getFileById("...file ID of a Google Sheet...");
var newFileDestination = DriveApp.getFolderById("...folder ID of destination folder...")
var newFile = template.makeCopy("new file name", newFileDestination)
```

However, it is worth noting, that the auto-subscribe to comment notifications also happens if you manually make a copy of a file.

** EDIT 3 **

The issue of auto-subscribe to comments/notifications for new files can be manually reproduced:

1. Create a brand new Google Sheet file
2. Set comment notifications for this new file (#1) to **Only yours** -- see "Manage your comment notifications" in https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129?guide=1208624&visit_id=637353849233956627-596889868&rd=2 for how
3. Create a copy of the new file (#1) - `File > Make a copy`
4. Now, if you check the copy (#2) you will see that comment notifications are back to **All**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221316/discussion-on-question-by-imthenachoman-disable-auto-comment-notifications-for-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment of this answer there is no method in Apps Script to disable comment notifications in Documents. If you want to request this feature to be added, you can file a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/support#missing_features).

### Workaround

Alternatively, in your Spreadsheet you can head over to **Tools-> Notification Rules** and delete the ones you might have. You can also head to the comment icon in the top right of the page and set the notifications to **None** or **Only you**.

However, as new files are created by copying from the original file they might get their settings reset and therefore keep sending the comment notifications. One workaround to avoid getting too many of these in your mail inbox is to set a [label](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7326859?hl=en) in your Gmail account to handle these (either by archiving or deleting them).